# Heap memory exploration with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I've written a program that takes 3 number in input:

- 1. The size of memory to allocate in the heap with `malloc()`
- 2. Two `int` value

If `q` is an `unsigned char` pointer it gives `q[i]=b` from `q[min]` to `q[max]`.

I thought that the heap was divided in pages and that the first call to `malloc()` would have given a pointer to the first byte of the page of my process. So why if try to get `q[-1]` my process is not killed?

Then I've tried with another pointer `p` and I noticed that between the two pointers there is a distance of 32byte, why they are not adjacent?

The last thing I notice is that both in `p[-8]=q[-40(-32-8)]` and `q[-8]` there is the number `33 00100001` (all the other bytes are setted to 0), it means anything?

Thank you!

Comment: Meditate about the implications of **undefined** behaviour. Please point to the section in the standard which requires a specific allocation scheme for dynamic memory. There is not even a heap-based mechanism required.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that the heap was divided in pages and that the first call to malloc would have given a pointer to the first byte of the page of my process. So why if try to get q[-1] my process is not killed?

Most likely because your `malloc` implementation stores something there. Possibly the size of the block.

> Then I've tried with another pointer p and I noticed that between the two pointers there is a distance of 32byte, why they are not adjacents?

Same reason. Your implementation probably stores the size of the block in the block just before the address it returns.

> The last thing I notice is that both in p[-8]=q[-40(-32-8)] and q[-8] there is the number 33 (00100001), it means anything?

It probably means something to your `malloc` implementation. But you can't really tell what without looking at the implementation.

Comment: I use this version of gcc `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: I can go to q[-50] and maybe more and the process is not killed

Comment: @sworwitz The implementation may allocate large chunks, split them up, and give out the last block first. There's really no way to be sure other than to look at the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library uses the heap before calling main so anything you do won't be on a clean heap.
The heap implementation usually uses about 2 pointer at the starting of an allocation, and the total size is usually aligned to 2 pointers.
The heap implementation usually uses a lot of bytes at the start of each system allocation, it can sometimes be close to page size.
The heap is allocated in chunks much bigger than a page, on Windows it is at least 16 pages.
The heap can be adjacent to other allocations, on Linux it appeares right after the main executable so underflowing it won't crash.